# Can I add a dynamic method to an interface in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Can I add a dynamic method to an interface in c#?

So the interface method doesn't exist but exists on the underlying class and I want to call it via an interface.

thanks

Comment: Simple answer no..Why would u want to do that?

Comment: No, you can't do that because if the interface method didn't exist, then how could the interface call it? It would have no idea. The closest thing you could do would be to cast the interface method to an object of the underlying class, however, you kinda lose your polymorphic abilities by doing this. My suggestion to you is to rethink what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of defeats the point of an interface. If you want it on some of the classes and not others then you can implement it that way, but you will have to cast it to the known class type first.

You could probably use some reflection to check in the under-laying class type has the method you want to call if you want to be really fussy about it (and avoid knowing the type to cast)

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new interface that implements the original interface as a sort of "middle man" between your class and the underlying interface

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string PropA { get; set; }
}

public interface IFooExtended
{
    void MyMethod();
}

public class ConcreteFoo : IFooExtended
{
    // implementation...
}
```

It's not "dynamic" but this may help.

Answer (score 0):

No - you could add an extension method to the interface to achieve a similar objective.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right practice to follow that is as close as possible to what you're trying to achieve is create a new interface that inherits the old one.

Something like:

```
interface IMyInterface : IExistingInterface
{
   void MyCustomMethod();
}
```

And you will address your new interface in your code. The classes implementing it will have your new method as well as the methods of the inherited interface.

You can't alter an existing interface, that would defeat the purpose of an interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you want to use a dynamic *interface* (e.g., strong-typed duck typing like in Visual Basic), then **no**, C# doesn't natively support this. But you can check out the Code Project article, [*Dynamic interfaces in any .NET language*](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/gointerfaces.aspx).